# How to search all Stack Exchange sites for a specific tag

Tags: support, tags, search

(I'm assuming that some tags exist on more than one site.)

e.g. I tried doing search across all sites (i.e. here on META), for the tag iOS, by using syntax of [iOS],
but the results seem to indicate that it's just finding string matches, rather than restricting the search to just tags.

If this is even possible, what should such a search's syntax look like?

Comment: Hmm...a counter-example is that the tag [tags] exists in both StackOverflow and Meta.  (Maybe this has something to do with 'global' tags!?  But, I haven't digested that concept yet.)

Comment: I’m not sure you want all of the questions tagged cookies. Unless you have an urge for a snack while dealing with web tracking.

Comment: I consider this question as ANSWERED.  Thx for the comments.and pointer to the similar question.